# I have problems with tkinter icon in python 3.7 (MacOS Mojave)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, macos-mojave

I use python 3.7 with MacOS Mojave and I was trying to put an icon into a tkinter window but it doesn't appear:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.iconbitmap("programme2/planeacion1.ico")

root.mainloop()
```

[tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWWdJ.png)

I'm sure that the `.ico` file is in the folder and there are no errors when I run it so I don't know what happened.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run it and there's only the `title` and a white sheet in the left like an empty icon

Comment: Ok, try using a `.png` instead of a `.ico`

Comment: Nothing happens and I also tried putting the complete path

Comment: If it don't raise error,it means your path is right.Are you sure your image is `.ico` format?(You didn't rename it to `.ico`,right?)

Comment: I used an online png to ico converter

Comment: try other image as  code is working fine at my end

Comment: Sorry dexter but I didn't understand

Comment: Is your size of ico `32x32`?Try to use `32x32`.

Comment: I'll try with 32 x 32